# static-files 404 not found on hosted django app

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, django-staticfiles

im having a hard time to display my static files on my webpages, im hosting my website on digitalocean ubuntu 18 and my static files are stored on the digitalocean space. initially everything was okay and working correctly until i added 3 new images to the server and ran the collectstatic command afterwards, note this was for the second time cause i ran it the first time to store the files in the digitalocean space folder i created. The collectstatic command shown me a warning saying

> UserWarning: The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change in django-storages 2.0. By default files and new buckets are saved with an ACL of 'public-read' (globally publicly readable). Version 2.0 will default to using the bucket's ACL. To opt into the new behavior set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None, otherwise to silence this warning explicitly set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL. "The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change "

after i continue by typing yes, the files are images are successfully stored in the digital-space, but ever since i ran the collect command for the second time all staticfile are not displayed. I did some further reading about this warning and used the solution from [AWS S3 and Django returns "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722355/aws-s3-and-django-returns-an-error-occurred-accessdenied-when-calling-the-put/53436202) but still nothing changed the warning went away but the staticfiles are still not found.

heres the error message from the chrome browser: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Answer (score 0):

have you ensured your settings display this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join('static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Following this, your templates should show the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/locationofstatics/css/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/locationofstatics/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
```

The best way to go about things in my opinion is to only collecstatic locally and then push all of the local files and directories up to the server. What do you currently use to transfer files to the server side?

The other thing you need to do is ensure that Nginx has the location of your static files set within the sites-available file. From your ssh terminal (server side terminal) you can type:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/projectname
```

Within this you need to add the location of your statics, for example:

```
server {

ocation /static/ {
        root /home/name/projectname;
    }
}
```

The following documents are extremely useful:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: i have been using using those tutorials and then followed along a newer tutorial verson which configured whats called digitalocean space for staticfiles, but cant seem to get things to work i keep getting the 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I was using nginx server in digitalocean for my django project.
front-end static files were working but admin not.

See my static files setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

front-end css in static folder and collectstatic target folder is staticfiles

**So our main focus is STATIC_ROOT means staticfiles folder. In nginx settings put "staticfiles" instead of "static" to set static file location.**

**Your STATIC_ROOT folder name could be anything you need to use that same name in nginx.**

See below code for nginx setting:

```
location /staticfiles/ {
    root /home/[your_username]/[your_project_folder];
}
```

[your_username]: which you are using to host your project on digitalocean.

The whole thing is that, you need to use your STATIC_ROOT folder in nginx setting.

Command to create/edit nginx setting is:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/[your_project_folder]
```